# How do I add a multi-table case statement to a @hybrid_property expression?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a `@hybrid_property` in a 'parent' table with a case statement that outputs a `datetime` value from a 'child' table if one exists. If it doesn't then it should output the `datetime` value from the original table. As the relationship between the two tables will be one-to-one then I'm following the guide [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one).

I've put together this MRE:

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, DateTime, case, create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
import datetime as dt

Base = declarative_base()

class TblParent(Base):

    __tablename__ = "tbl_parent"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "test"}

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime)

    tbl_child_rel = relationship("TblChild", back_populates="tbl_parent_rel", uselist=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def date_time_hybrid(self):
        return

    @date_time_hybrid.expression
    def date_time_hybrid(cls):
        return case(
            [
                (cls.tbl_child_rel.date_time.__ne__(None), cls.tbl_child_rel.date_time),
            ],
            else_=cls.date_time,
        )


class TblChild(Base):

    __tablename__ = "tbl_child"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "test"}

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime)
    tbl_parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("test.tbl_parent.id_"), unique=True)

    tbl_parent_rel = relationship("TblParent", back_populates="tbl_child_rel")


engine = create_engine(cn.CONN_STRING)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session.add(TblParent(id_=1, date_time=dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)))
session.add(TblChild(id_=1, date_time=dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1), tbl_parent_id=1))
session.commit()
qry = session.query(TblParent.date_time_hybrid)
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with TblParent.tbl_child has an attribute 'date_time'
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance!

I'm using python 3.9.6 and sqlalchemy 1.4.23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below should work:

```
@hybrid_property
def date_time_hybrid(self):
    return self.tbl_child_rel and self.tbl_child_rel.date_time or self.date_time

@date_time_hybrid.expression
def date_time_hybrid(cls):
    subq = (
        select([TblChild.date_time.label("date_time")])
        .where(TblChild.tbl_parent_id == cls.id_)
        .scalar_subquery()
    )
    return func.ifnull(subq, cls.date_time).label("date_time_hybrid")
```

---

Fully contained working example below:

```
import datetime as dt

from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    DateTime,
    ForeignKey,
    Integer,
    create_engine,
    func,
    select,
)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class TblParent(Base):

    __tablename__ = "tbl_parent"
    # __table_args__ = {"schema": "test"}

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime)

    tbl_child_rel = relationship(
        "TblChild", back_populates="tbl_parent_rel", uselist=False
    )

    @hybrid_property
    def date_time_hybrid(self):
        return self.tbl_child_rel and self.tbl_child_rel.date_time or self.date_time

    @date_time_hybrid.expression
    def date_time_hybrid(cls):
        subq = (
            select([TblChild.date_time.label("date_time")])
            .where(TblChild.tbl_parent_id == cls.id_)
            .scalar_subquery()
        )
        return func.ifnull(subq, cls.date_time).label("date_time_hybrid")


class TblChild(Base):

    __tablename__ = "tbl_child"
    # __table_args__ = {"schema": "test"}

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_time = Column(DateTime)
    tbl_parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tbl_parent.id_"), unique=True)

    tbl_parent_rel = relationship("TblParent", back_populates="tbl_child_rel")


CONN_STRING = "sqlite:///:memory:"
engine = create_engine(CONN_STRING, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

parents = (p_no_child_no_dt, p_no_child_dt, p_child_no_dt, p_child_dt,) = (
    TblParent(id_=1, date_time=None),
    TblParent(id_=2, date_time=dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)),
    TblParent(id_=3, date_time=dt.datetime(2000, 1, 2), tbl_child_rel=TblChild()),
    TblParent(
        id_=4,
        date_time=dt.datetime(2000, 1, 3),
        tbl_child_rel=TblChild(date_time=dt.datetime(2000, 1, 4)),
    ),
)
session.add_all(parents)
session.commit()
# qry = session.query(TblParent.date_time_hybrid)

# in-memory
session.expunge_all()
qry = session.query(TblParent)
for p in qry.all():
    print(p.id_, p.date_time_hybrid)

print("-" * 80)

# query
session.expunge_all()
qry = session.query(TblParent.id_, TblParent.date_time_hybrid)
for p in qry:
    print(p)
```

Comment: Thanks! I’ve had to send my laptop in fo repair so can’t check this. I’ve awarded the bounty as it was running out. When my laptop is back then I’ll check things and mark as accepted :-)